# How to unlock Angulars mat-date-range-picker while using min/max via functions?

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I'm try to set Angulars [mat-date-range-picker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#date-range-selection) min & max via component methods.

While property binding works fine, **a binding via methods seems to block the ui of the range picker.**

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {FormControl, FormGroup} from "@angular/forms";

const dateOffset = (24*60*60*1000) * 5; //5 days

@Component({
    selector: 'example-component',
    template: `
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Doesn't work</mat-label>
            <mat-date-range-input [formGroup]="range2" [rangePicker]="picker2" [min]="getMin()" [max]="getMax()">
                <input matStartDate formControlName="start"
                       placeholder="Start date">
                <input matEndDate formControlName="end"
                       placeholder="End date">
            </mat-date-range-input>
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-date-range-picker #picker2></mat-date-range-picker>
        </mat-form-field>
    `
})

export class ExampleComponent {

    range2 = new FormGroup({
        start: new FormControl(),
        end: new FormControl()
    });

    getMin() {
        let min = new Date();
        min.setTime(this.now.getTime() - dateOffset);
        return min;
    }

    getMax() {
        let max = new Date();
        max.setTime(this.now.getTime() + dateOffset);
        return max;
    }
}
```

Depending [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-date-range-fn-bug-22gezs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexample-component.ts) with working and blocking variant.

What i'm doing wrong here?